# Change the value of the leaves of a tree with the sum of the path from root to leaf

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have to create a function that took a tree t not empty, change the content of each leaf in its field by putting the sum of the values contained in the nodes of the path from the root to the leaf (including root and leaf).

So I created this:

```
void sum(BinTree t) {
    while(!t.isLeaf()) {
        sumL += sum(t.left);
        sumR += sum(t.right);
    }
    t.element = ?;
}

boolean isLeaf(BinTree t) {
    return t.left == null && t.right == null;
}
```

What should I put in place of "?"? I don't think that the function is correct..
I'm unable to create recursive functions for the binary trees, I find them very complicated..

Thanks

---

EDIT: I changhed my method:

```
void leafSum(BinTree t) {
    sumLeaf(root, 0);
}

void leafSum(BinTree t, int tot) {
    if(t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL)
        t->elem = tot;
    else {
        sumLeaf(t->left, tot + t->elem);
        sumLeaf(t->right, tot + t->elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to sound harsh, but that mean you need to try more, and study more. How would *you* perform this task?

Comment: Check out this wiki article on tree traversal: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Java There are examples in Java that you can copy and paste and only have to modify for the math. And yes, all the examples are recursive. While it's possible to traverse a tree w/o recursion it is widely considered an ugly solution.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than providing a solution I'll give a few hints to help you along. Ask questions if any of it isn't clear.

- The basic algorithm you are looking for is: for each node if it's a leaf then store the sum, if it's not a leaf then repeat for both child nodes.
- While recursion isn't essential it will make the solution simpler in this case. It's not complex: the basic rule is to always have a termination condition (in your case, that you are looking at a leaf) before recursing.
- You should pass a running total to the function so that you don't need to look back up the tree once you get to a leaf. That's not complex: just add the current value for the node to the running total before storing it (for leaves) or passing it to child node (for non-leaves).
- Start with a running total of zero when you call the function for the root node.

That's about it - you should be able to come up with a solution from those hints.